# xml js simply find attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm loading xml and then getting data with js. My question is every time I need to find an  attribute do I have to execute a function?

```
$(document).find("Item").each(function(){
}
```

I want to say

```
$(document).find("Item").eq(0).attr("title")
```

However this only works when I place it in the function

```
 function parse(document){
 }
```

This is my xml

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'data.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parse,
    error: function(){alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");}
});
```

Comment: Question is a little unclear; what do you mean by "only works when I place it in a function"?  My wild guess is that you have an issue with the scope of `document`.

Comment: @user2238083 - Please accept the answer, if the solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

### You can use [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="someElement"></p>
        <p id="anotherElement"></p>
        <script>
            var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
                xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                $xml = $(xmlDoc),
                $title = $xml.find("title");

            /* append "RSS Title" to #someElement */
            $("#someElement").append($title.text());

            /* change the title to "XML Title" */
            $title.text("XML Title");

            /* append "XML Title" to #anotherElement */
            $("#anotherElement").append($title.text());
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```